# Less wont apply Tailwind CSS classname with dot (.)

Tags: less, tailwind-css

How to apply a Tailwind CSS classname that includes a dot with Less? Escaping (\) didn't worked.
I can use this code without any problems in Sass:

```
@apply py-0.5;
```

> Syntax error: The `0.5` class does not exist. If you're sure that
> `0.5` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being
> properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can
> only be used for classes in the same CSS tree. (7:4)

Other Tailwind CSS classnames just work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely related to how Less parses the input. You could [use `~` to escape](http://lesscss.org/#escaping) the class name.

```css
@apply ~"py-0.5";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have googled it, no idea what happened (also it's on the first place!). Hope this question/topic will help someone else too =) Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know how to do the same in SCSS ?

Comment: @Tonio This might be relevant to you: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/strings#escapes.